# PHP: for each loop is displaying only last element

Tags: php

actually I am trying to upload multiple images using php and I am using foreach loop to upload images but I am Abel to loop first image but not second image I am not receiving second image and I observed that my loop is returning only last element

```
$uploadedFiles = $_FILES['imagefile'];

$files = [];

if(count($uploadedFiles) > 1) {

    foreach((array)$uploadedFiles['name'] as $key => $name) {
        $files[$key]['name'] = $name;
        $files[$key]['type'] = $uploadedFiles['type'][$key];
        $files[$key]['tmp_name'] = $uploadedFiles['tmp_name'][$key];
        $files[$key]['error'] = $uploadedFiles['error'][$key];
        $files[$key]['size'] = $uploadedFiles['size'][$key];
    }

} else {
    // Handle single uploaded file
}

var_dump($files);
```

[image]

Comment: What is the `(array)$imageFileDetails=...` in the foreach supposed to be good for? Especially considering that you are _overwriting_ `$imageFileDetails` in each loop iteration.

Comment: Have you `echo` the `$_FILES` or the `$key` in the loop?

Comment: ya it is displayed empty while I am writing echo

Comment: when I am writing echo $ key they I am receiving Array as out put

Comment: @CBroe if I remove (array) in for each I am facing  foreach() argument must be of type array|object, error

Comment: The cast might be required, but the assignment to a variable at that point isn't.

Comment: ok now I had observed loop is running only once

Comment: PHP overwrites GET/POST parameters with the same name, unless you use "array syntax" in the name - your `imagefile` parameters need to be named `imagefile[]`.

Comment: @CBroe I had tried in different ways like...` $uploadedFiles = $_FILES[ "image file[]"];`I am facing error  Undefined array key "imagefile[]" can you pleas show me the right syntax to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and I observed that my loop is returning only last element

PHP overwrites GET/POST parameters with the same name, unless you use "array syntax" in the name - your `imagefile` parameters need to be named `imagefile[]`.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php#example-103

Comment: exactly I had did the same as link $uploadedFiles = $_FILES[ "image file[]"];`I am facing error Undefined array key "imagefile[]"

Comment: I am talking about the parameters you are _sending_ - the `imagefile` in your Postman request. _Accessing_ the values will still happen via `$_FILES['imagefile']`.

Comment: hmm it is working thank you but it is entering into 'if(!isset($_FILES['imagefile']) || $_FILES['imagefile']['error'] !== 0) {'

Comment: The structure of $_FILES is different for multiple uploads, https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php

Comment: I had tried to check   if(!isset(is_array($_FILES['imagefile'])) || isset(is_array($_FILES['imagefile'])) this way but not working I don't want enter this condition if imagefile. exist can you please help me to write condition if file exist

Comment: `isset(is_array())` makes no sense - `isset` checks if a _variable_ is set, but `is_array` just returns a boolean.

Comment: Checking if `$_FILES['imagefile']` actually exists, should be sufficient here. If the request parameter(s) are named `imagefile[]`- then this _will_ be an array, even if you uploaded only a single file. And whether an array is empty or not does not need checking before you `foreach` over it - a foreach over an empty array, simply does nothing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248756/discussion-between-santosh-kumar-and-cbroe).